# Image after uploading don't have equal space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

after I upload Images the images have differen space in the table. I mean the space between each image is different.

I am using this:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">



            <tr>

               <th style="width: 10%"><h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)</h4></th>
               <th style="width: 30%"><h4> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</h4></th>
                <th style="width: 120%"></th>

            </tr>


            <tr>


                <td>
                    <img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new {id = Model.Id  })">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th><h2><br /></h2></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
                    {

                      <th style="width:10%"> <img src="~/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" height=150 width=200 /></th>
                    }





            </tr>







        </table>
    </div>
```

and this is the loop for the images:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
                        {

                          <th style="width:10%"> <img src="~/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" height=150 width=200 /></th>
                        }
```

[image]

The Image I uploaded says it all.

Thank you

Comment: Your table is totally wrong. Each row (`tr`) MUST have the same number of cells (`td` or `th`). If not you MUST use `colspan`so that the number of cells equals that of the row with the most cells. Your fist row has 3 cells. Your second 1 cell. Your 4th row looks as though it could have an arbitrary number of cells etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First why `<th style="width: 120%"></th>` ? width will be equal to 70%
After i suggest you to use a css grid instead of table

Comment: cool i do a little error it's not 70% but 100 - (30+10) = 60% :)